# How to improve Magento performance by eliminating Apache .htaccess files?

Tags: magento2, performance, htaccess, apache2

Our setup is a Magento 2.3.3 store running on a dedicated (not shared) Linux host. We have full root access and can edit files as needed. The httpd server is Apache 2.4.41.

We have read several good articles on improving Magento performance. In those that we have seen, no mention is made of the fact that **`.htaccess` files slow down Apache (and nginx) web servers**.

In our `pub` directory, we have these `.htaccess` files:

```
pub/.htaccess
pub/errors/.htaccess
pub/media/.htaccess
pub/media/customer/.htaccess
pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess
pub/media/import/.htaccess
pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
pub/static/.htaccess
```

How can we address this?

Answer (score 1):

Every time Apache accesses a directory, it will look for an `.htaccess` file in that directory as well as in the parent directory -- and the parent's parent directory, all the way up to the way up to the root of the DocumentRoot! Think about what that does on every request when your site is busy. Addressing this is actually very simple.

The [official recommendation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) for `.htaccess` files from the Apache Foundation (**When (not) to use .htaccess files**) says:

> **you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have access to the main server configuration file.**

In this case, access is available to the main server configuration files, so we can eliminate the `.htaccess` files. You do that by "Including" the fully qualified filename in your virtual host file. The default virtual host file is often `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

Below the ending `</VirtualHost>` directive add a Directory directive for each `.htaccess` file similar to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/magento2/pub/">
    AllowOverRide None
    Include /var/www/html/magento2/pub/.htaccess
</directory>
```

You must include `AllowOverRide None` or Apache will continue to read the `.htaccess` files.

Any easy way to generate all the required "Directory" directives is to use some bash commands like this. **Set your own `magento_documentroot` path first**, then run this is a bash shell:

```
magento_documentroot="/var/www/html/magento2"
for dirn in $(find $magento_documentroot/pub -type f -iname ".htaccess" -exec dirname {} \;)
do
echo "<Directory \"$dirn\">
    AllowOverRide None
    Include $dirn/.htaccess
</directory>"
echo
done
```

Paste the resulting Directory directives into the appropriate virtual host file as mentioned above.

Then restart Apache and check that it started correctly. On a systemd system the commands are:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service 
systemctl status httpd.service
```

Then make sure you can access the Magento site as expected.

Caveat: I recommend you read this before proceeding with the above steps:

[Modify docroot to improve security | Magento 2 Developer Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)

You may notice that in the above steps we only addressed `.htaccess` files in `pub`. The reason why is because the site was set up according to the Magento recommendations above where `pub` is the DocumentRoot.

Are there any disadvantages to moving the `.htaccess` files into virtual host configuration files? One reason often cited in favor of using `.htaccess` files is that they can be checked in to your version control tool as part of your project. However, with this method, you can eliminate the performance hit while retaining the ability to use version control tools on the `.htaccess` files (or benefit from any changes made by Magento or vendors when you update).

For more information, see this [blog](https://stefanxo.com/move-your-htaccess-files-into-your-virtualhosts-file/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836359/how-come-i-cant-move-the-contents-of-my-htaccess-file-into-my-virtual-host).

Comment: thanks for a very detailed solution

Comment: obviously there is zero to 0.001% gain...

Comment: @MagenX - not according to Apache. Removing .htaccess files is one of the most important changes you can make. The Apache docs explain why it is so important.